# Wikidata query with values from CSV-File

Tags: csv, wikidata

I would like to do a Wikidata query of many values that are listed in a column of a CSV file on my computer.
How can I load the values from the CSV file into the Wikidata query automatically without copying them in manually?

So far I have worked with the Wikidata query in Visual Studio Code.

This is the [query](https://w.wiki/6FmL) I made for one person:

```
SELECT ?Author ?AuthorLabel ?VIAF ?birthLocation
   WHERE {
   VALUES ?VIAF {"2467372"}
   ?Author wdt:P214 ?VIAF ;
     wdt:P19 ?birthLocation .
           
   SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_Language],de". }              
}
```

I want to automatically load many values into the curly brackets of the query above from the column of my CSV file.

Comment: Are such values stored in a single column?
Are they just item identifiers or they also have a `wd:` prefix?
By "automatic" do you mean in a programmatic way or are you also ok with semi-automatic ways like a notepad find & replace tool?
Please update your question with such information.

Comment: Yes, such values are stored in a single column in the CSV-file.
They are just item identifiers like Q49227399 without a wd-prefix.
I would like to have an automatic way. I know a semi-automatic way would be possible with OpenRefine but I would like to have an automatic process.

Comment: What programming language do you want to use for automatize this process? What have you already tried?

Comment: Nothing so far, I am new to this topic.
My preferred programming language would be python but I am still learning.

Comment: Your starting query doesn't run. Can you please update it to a working [example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? A Also, the example entity, Q49227399, appears to be a place in Norway, which is unlikely to have either a VIAF ID or a birth location.

Comment: Thanks (even though that's a completely different query!)

Answer (score 0):

So, say you have a file `my_file.csv` with the following content:

```
2467372
63468347
12447
```

First of all, import a python library for reading files (like `fileinput`).

Then declare the pattern that you want to use for your query, using `%s` as placeholder for the identifiers.

Now, build a list of identifiers as follows:

```py
identifiers = ['wd:'+line.strip() for line in fileinput.input(files='my_file.csv')]
```

And finally join the list using a space character as separator and pass this string to your query pattern:

```py
query = query_pattern % ' '.join(identifiers)
```

This is the final code:

```py
import fileinput

filename = 'my_file.csv'
query_pattern = '''SELECT ?Author ?AuthorLabel ?VIAF ?birthLocation
   WHERE {
   VALUES ?VIAF { %s }
   ?Author wdt:P214 ?VIAF ;
     wdt:P19 ?birthLocation .
           
   SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_Language],de". }              
}'''

identifiers = ['"'+line.strip()+'"' for line in fileinput.input(files=filename)]
query = query_pattern % ' '.join(identifiers)
print(query)
```

Executing it, you'll get:

```
SELECT ?Author ?AuthorLabel ?VIAF ?birthLocation
   WHERE {
   VALUES ?VIAF { "2467372" "63468347" "12447" }
   ?Author wdt:P214 ?VIAF ;
     wdt:P19 ?birthLocation .

   SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_Language],de". }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I feel compelled to point out that if you don't already know a programming language OpenRefine can do this for you in a few clicks.

Having said that, here's a basic Python program that accomplishes what you literally asked for - reading a set of VIAF ids and adding them to your query:

```
import csv


def expand_query(ids):
    query = """
    SELECT ?Author ?AuthorLabel ?VIAF ?birthLocation ?birthLocationLabel WHERE {
        VALUES ?VIAF {
        """ + '"' + '" "'.join(ids) + '"' """
        }
        ?Author wdt:P214 ?VIAF. 
        OPTIONAL { ?Author wdt:P19 ?birthLocation. }
        SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_Language],de,en". }
    }
    """
    return query


def main():
    with open('../data/authors.csv', "rt") as csvfile:
        csvreader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, dialect=csv.excel)
        ids = [row["viaf"] for row in csvreader]
        print(expand_query(ids))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

It expects a CSV file with a column called `viaf` and will ignore all other columns. e.g.

```
name,viaf
Douglas Adams,113230702
William Shakespeare,96994048
Bertolt Brecht,2467372
```

I've tweaked the query slightly to:

- always output a row even if the birth location isn't available
- output the label for the birth location
- add English as an additional fallback language for labels

This makes the assumption that you've got a small enough set of identifiers to be able to use a single query, but you can extended it to:

- read identifiers in batchs of a convenient size
- use [SPARQLwrapper](https://sparqlwrapper.readthedocs.io) to send the results to the Wikidata SPARQL endpoint and parse the results
- write the results to a different CSV file in chunks as they're received